# MySQL select statement similar to entered value

Tags: mysql, select

I've been searching all over and trying out different approaches but I'm just not getting what I need.

Is there a possibility in MySQL to select a db entry similar to a string value entered in a form?

for example: I have a db with vendor names in it and a customer can enter a vendor name into a search field. Let's say he's looking for adobe but accidentally types 'adope' in the search field. I would now like to select all entries, that are similar to 'adope'. How can I do that?

I've tried ... LIKE '%$vendor%' and all kinds of regexp but it seems I'm on the wrong way...

Thanks fpr your help in advance :-)

Cheers

Fred

Answer (score 3):

You can do with `SOUNDEX`, check out this tutorial:

- [Mysql function to soundex match a word in a multi word string](http://www.imranulhoque.com/mysql/mysql-function-soundex-match-multi-word-string/)

[Also check out the official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

> Returns a soundex string from str. Two
>   strings that sound almost the same
>   should have identical soundex strings.
>   A standard soundex string is four
>   characters long, but the SOUNDEX()
>   function returns an arbitrarily long
>   string. You can use SUBSTRING() on the
>   result to get a standard soundex
>   string.

Comment: Hey Sarfraz! Thanks for quick answer :-) Works like a charm: SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE expr1 SOUNDS LIKE expr2 :-) Thank you very much :-D